# How to format xml string for Drools KIE server?

Tags: drools

Currently, I build Drools rule package (a *.jar file) in Drools Workbench, and deploy it to a KIE server container. To request the service, I just post a XML command like below to the container, which is excerpted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551535/setup-drools-kie-execution-server-credentials):

```
<batch-execution lookup="defaultKieSession">
<insert out-identifier="message" return-object="true" entry-point="DEFAULT">
    <com.arty.drlwb.MyExampleType>
          <message>Hello Worlddddd</message>
    </com.arty.drlwb.MyExampleType>
</insert>
<fire-all-rules/>
</batch-execution>
```

I can get what I expected. Everything seems OK.

But I found there are [two KieSessions in the rule package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34127702/why-are-there-two-kiesession-in-jar-file-created-by-drools-workbench) and don't know which one will be used. If the stateful one is used, and I the post XML command with different facts (messages here) over and over again, all facts will be kept in Drools' working memory as far as I know.

Then, **would it cause memory leakage since there's no retract command?** If yes, what's the **correct way** to format the XML command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session you want to use for a batch execution in kie-server can be specified by the attribute `lookup` in the `<batch-execution>` element. In your case, the KieSession with name `defaultKieSession` will be used.

If no `lookup` attribute is specified, then the KieSession defined as the default (`default="true"`) in the kmodule.xml will be selected. If multiple default sessions are specified in the kmodule.xml (just like in your previous post), then I'm not sure which one will be selected. I would say that it is always a good practice to provide the `lookup` attribute in your `<batch-execution>` element to avoid confusion.

Regarding the retraction of facts, given that this operation was renamed as "delete" in Drools 6.x, the command you are looking for is `org.drools.core.command.runtime.rule.DeleteObjectCommand`. Oddly enough, this command is still being serialized as `<retract>`.

Hope it helps,